# (rails) SVG: saturate принимает только интервал 0..1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

На вьюхе svg saturate прекрасно работает. Верчу бегунок в пределах 0..5 - картинка меняется (Код вьюхи думаю не нужно приводить). Отправляю данные на сервер - при сохранении saturate='0.5' или '0.9' или '0.2' картинка меняется, при сохранении saturate='2.5' или '1.1' или '3.4' - уже игнорируются. Генерация svg строки на бекенде:

```
      "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
      <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='#{image_height}' width='#{image_width}'>
        <defs>
              <filter id='fp1'>
                <feComponentTransfer>
                  <feFuncR slope='#{r_component}' type='linear'></feFuncR>
                  <feFuncG slope='#{g_component}' type='linear'></feFuncG>
                  <feFuncB slope='#{b_component}' type='linear'></feFuncB>
                  <feFuncA type='identity'></feFuncA>
                </feComponentTransfer>
                <feColorMatrix type='saturate' values='#{saturate}'></feColorMatrix>
              </filter>
        </defs>
        <image filter='url(#fp1)' height='100%' width='100%' xlink:href='#{self.image.path}'></image>
      </svg>"
```

Заголовки, версии и фильтры в строке убирал - работает также.

Comment: приводится ли верняя граница 5 к 1-це?

Comment: не совсем понятен комментарий

Comment: данные не преобразовываются никак. с инпута отправляю "2.5", сохраяню "2.5", "2.5" игнорируется как значение.